# Components of fairness in income/reward division

Tags: io-psychology, reward

I'm looking for any analysis or research on how people tend to see fair division of income or reward for a given task or project.

On the market, political interventions aside, it seems to be the result of supply and demand laws. E.g. software developers may make good money but if suddenly a lot of people will get themselves trained for software development - this career path will get less profitable even if other conditions remain the same.

I'm looking for more psychological approach - what people tend to think is fair in an abstract setting?
Has anyone tried to formulate some kind of "just pay equation" where individual components of the equation would be things like labor hours, amount of time needed to acquire necessary skills (time required for training and/or education), the difficulty of the task, dangerous or unpleasant conditions associated with the work etc. with the parameters of the equation being weights of the components (the importance people ascribe to them)?

What other components may there be and what weights do people assign to them? How might their assessment differ based on culture, social status, personality etc.?

Where should I start looking if I want to know more about that?